# Best Method or Tool to Migrate from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

What is the best method or tool to migrate a database from MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server?

My database is MySQL 5.0.27 and has 74 tables and 41 stored procedures.

The current site is ASP/VBscript and uses dynamic SQL statements in the code. The stored procedures are mostly used in the mysql admin to manage specific tasks. It would be great to have the stored procedures be converted but I'm not that hopeful.

I have two goals:
1) Migrate the database from MySQL to SQL Server
2) Convert MySQL SQL statements in VBScript to SQL Server

There are a lot of datetime columns in the database and I expect to have a lot of problems with those during the conversion process.

Comment: To get a better answer, can you talk about how much data you're migrating, how many tables, how many databases, and what the client app is written in?  Your queries can change from MySQL to MSSQL, and you may want to include that as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the "best" but here is a tool http://www.dbload.com/

I'd probably use DTS / SSIS (with ODBC MySql Driver) that comes with Sql Server depending on how many objects you are transferring it may take awhile to get all the mappings/identity/defaults correct

Comment: Have you used DBLoad? If so how did it do? The database has about 80 tables and 24 or so stored procedures. I will probably have to recreate the stored procedures in SQL Server.

Comment: i have not, but I have done the DTC transfer

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://www.mydbexplorer.com